# Tizen CLI create project throws exception

Tags: command-line-interface, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

So, I'm using the Tizen-CLI but I can't even get passed the "create the project"-stage since I'm getting a crash. I'm running the following command:

`$ tizen create web-project -n heavenlydays -p wearable-3.0 -t WebBasicapplication`

That, for some reason, throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tizen/core/gputil/XMLUtil
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createweb.CreateWebProjectCommand.generateFileFromRegenTemplate(CreateWebProjectCommand.java:640)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createweb.CreateWebProjectCommand.generateFilefromProjectRoot(CreateWebProjectCommand.java:473)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createweb.CreateWebProjectCommand.processOption(CreateWebProjectCommand.java:453)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createweb.CreateWebProjectCommand.call(CreateWebProjectCommand.java:154)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createweb.CreateWebProjectCommand.call(CreateWebProjectCommand.java:96)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:85)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateWebProjectCLI.execute(CreateWebProjectCLI.java:92)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateCLI.execute(CreateCLI.java:39)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:85)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:143)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tizen.core.gputil.XMLUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

This is making it slightly difficult to get started. There are a bunch of weirdness such as the template name being *almost* camelCase but not quite. I've also tried using the **WebBasicApplication** but that doesn't work either as it is not even found.

**EDIT:**

My java version is 1.8.0_121, Tizen version is 1.4.19, I'm running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to run the 'list' command first.

```
$tizen list web-project
```

It would list you down the available project templates and profiles. Then you might chose your 'create web-project' command giving your preferred parameters.
As:

```
$ tizen create web-project -n testProject -p wearable-3.0 -t WebBasicapplication
```

By the way name of the template showing in the list is '**W**eb**B**asic**a**pplication'

[image]

If you are interested in installing native development environment, Run package manager cli.

```
 $ cd ~/tizen-studio/package-manager
 ~/tizen-studio/package-manager$ ./package-manager-cli.bin show-pkgs
```

The command would display the list of packages available

(ni- not installed)

(i- installed)

Install desired packages using 'install' command. Example:

```
~/tizen-studio/package-manager$ ./package-manager-cli.bin   install   WEARABLE-3.0  --accept-licence   -p ******
```

-p parameter takes the OS admin login password

I've tested on Ubuntu 14.04 machine, Please check the [CLI Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli) for details implementation.

[This link in Tizen Developers Forum](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites#java) says, Do not install OpenJDK, You have to use  Oracle JDK version 8 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for an extensive answer. I do have NativeCLI and NativeIDE installed according to the `update-manager-cli show-pkgs` so that's even stranger. I have noticed the weird camelCase-errors so that's not it. As you can see in my question my create command looks correct. What else apart from a missing Native CLI (which I have) could it be?

Comment: I tried a new approach and installed **every single package** that was available in the tizen-update-manager and it still doesn't work. Something feels slightly broken here :)

Comment: So you are using Oracle JDK? If that's the case then I think it's time for a fresh installation after uninstalling whole Tizen Studio.

Comment: What do you mean? I have JDK version 1.8.0_121. I just upgraded it before starting with Tizen. Are you saying I should reinstall Tizen Studio?

Comment: ```
git clone https://notabug.org/tizen/tizen-helper
make -f $PWD/tizen-helper/bin/mk-tizen-app.mk
```

Comment: I meant did you install java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html instead of http://openjdk.java.net/install/ , If yes Then I am suggesting for a re-installation

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I encounter same error here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install NativeCLI package before

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/SDK#java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:_org.2Ftizen.2Fcore.2Fgputil.2FXMLUtil

Comment: I've read that piece and it doesn't actually say where to download that and I've searched for it. Do you have an URL?

Comment: I checked it and I already had it installed, so that's not the problem.

Comment: I would try to install all available packages and try again

Answer (score 0):

I am making a script to automate some tizen tasks:

In your project dir try:

`git clone https://notabug.org/tizen/tizen-helper
make -f $PWD/tizen-helper/bin/mk-tizen-app.mk`

It's still a work in progress, but worked for me.

If you need support reach community at:

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Meeting#